# What was the nature of the sanctions that Arizona secretary of state and Governor-elect Katie Hobbs asked to be placed on Kari Lake?

Tags: united-states, election, governor

The title of Axios' December 27, 2022 [Arizona judge rules out sanctions against Kari Lake but orders $33,000 in fees](https://www.axios.com/2022/12/27/arizona-judge-kari-lake-lawsuit-court-fees) states the outcome of [Katie Hobbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katie_Hobbs)'s request (petition?) against [Kari Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kari_Lake).

On the same day, AZCentral's [Judge in Kari Lake case rejects sanctions, awards $33,000 in legal fees](https://www.azcentral.com/story/news/politics/elections/2022/12/27/kari-lake-facing-sanctions-legal-fees-governor-race-lawsuit/69758692007/) says

> The defendant attorneys, who represent the Maricopa County Board of Supervisors, Gov.-elect Hobbs, as well as Hobbs in her capacity as secretary of state, **argued sanctions are warranted because Lake presented a frivolous case that lacked any evidence to support her claims that problems with chain of custody and printers at Maricopa County vote centers were deliberate and led to her loss.**

**Question:** In what ways exactly did Hobbs request Lake to be sanctioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sanction is the way a court punishes violations of court rules. In this case, Hobbs was asking the court to sanction Lake in order to recover approximately $550,000 in legal fees and other expenses. The sanction was denied, although court costs of about $33,000 were permitted.

> However, Hobbs had asked the court Monday to award her $550,210 in attorney fees, with more than $450,000 going to top Democratic lawyer Marc Elias’ law firm. [[NY Post](https://nypost.com/2022/12/27/kari-lake-dodges-most-sanctions-for-arizona-election-challenge/)]

Other sources had estimated it may be as much as $600 to $700 thousand.